# Why is "Learning to Patch Synthesizers" locked?

Tags: discussion

Why is [Learning to Patch Synthesizers](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/32035/learning-to-patch-synthesizers-synth-theory) locked? Is it because the question is too vague? It has a lot of useful info in the answers that I don't know you'd find anywhere else.

I'm asking because one of the links is obsolete, and I was going to correct it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ironically the reason for your edit is the same reason behind the lock: it's a resource recommendation question that is prone to those effects and is one of the reasons they are considered off-topic.

The core question is at the bottom:

> There's got to be a name to the discipline, some kind of resource, some formalized, real thing around that particular science of music... right? Maybe additive is a bit of unexplored territory, but subtractive and FM are older than I am.
>
> Where should I be looking, to learn this kind of thing?

Resource recommendations questions have been a subject of debate and locking questions to show they should not be used to justify new questions has been done to help make the site consistent.